# Powershell: supply only an N-th parameter when calling a ComObject function

Tags: powershell, parameters

**I'm interested in how one supplies either a named argument to a ComObject function or how one supplies the default parameter without actually knowing the default value.**

**The task:**

Using PowerShell, open a Word document in a headless mode (without the Word Window), change the document direction and save it as a PDF file.

**The problem**

As per [the function documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835182.aspx), the parameter setting the document direction is roughly the 15th optional parameter. I either need to supply the preceding 14 parameters with their default value (which I so far could't figure how to do) or, better, I'd like to use something like VB's

```
Documents.Open FileName:="C:\MyFiles\Test.wp", DocumentDirection:=false
```

Other possibility were

```
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($file, $default, $default, ..., $default, wdLeftToRight)
```

but that is clearly the inferior solution.

**Minimal source**
This is what I have and it works fine except for the direction part.

```
$file=$args[0] 
$outputFile=$args[1] 

$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application 
$doc = $word.Documents.Open $file
$doc.SaveAs([ref] $outputFile, [ref] 17)

$doc.Close()
$word.Quit()
```

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544844/how-to-call-a-complex-com-method-from-powershell

Comment: Correct. You can't specify optional parameters in PowerShell. You have to give the whole list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could build something to do this with reflection. `GetMethod` returns a `MethodInfo`, which has a `GetProperty` method. It returns a `ParameterInfo` which has `DefaultValue, HasDefaultValue, and IsOptional` properties. So you could develop a PS function, say "InvokeWithNamedParameters" that emulates what VB supports.