# How to globally stop excel date autoformatting

Tags: excel, csv, date, autocorrect

I'm opening a csv file in excel and every time I open it, it changes some fields into dates when they are clearly not dates (they're CAS numbers, not that its important).  How do I stop this behavior? I know I can change the column format but this doesn't help when I first open the CSV file.

Comment: This question could be moved to superuser ...

Comment: You can enforce text value by `="2010-5-5"`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165042

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do while the file has `.csv` extension.  Excel has special handling for .csv files.  There is a way to deal with it, but it involves renaming the files to have some other extension.  You can rename `.csv` file to have extension `.txt`, for example, then open the `.txt` file with Excel: this time Excel will ask you to confirm details of the files for import.  At the first step, select *delimited*; at the second step, select *comma* as the delimiter and *double quote* for the quote element.  Finally, at the next step, you will have the option to specify the column formatting.  Just select all columns and select *text*, for example.  Alternatively, select the one column in question and choose *number* (although this risks getting scientific notation (1.23456E+10) if the numbers are long.

Comment: This was in 2012.. any news about new version of Excel ?

Comment: Nothing new in the newer excel version.

Comment: Just how unbelievably stupid this is. Shouldn't the default be number, not date when in Excel?

Answer (score 3):

If the files stay in csv format than they cannot retains any formatting choices that you make. So you have two choices:

1. Unformat the columns and save the file to .xls
2. Use the [Text Import Wizard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-import-wizard-HP010102244.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010099725) each time you wish at access this data. This tool give you the option to specify how the data will be interpreted by Excel.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting an apostrophe before every cell.

It will just make text cells, and will not appear as data in cells.

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  The OP needs to get correct formatting _before_ he/she can do anything with it.