# Exporting numeric vector as character to CSV

Tags: r, excel, csv, export, export-to-csv

Let the following vectors:

```
x <- c(123456789123456789, 987654321987654321)
y <- as.character(x)
```

I'm trying to export `y` into a csv file for later conversion into XLSX (don't ask, client requested), like so:

```
 write.csv(y, file = 'y.csv', row.names = F)
```

If I open `y.csv` in a pure word processor, I can see it has correctly inserted quotes around the elements, but when I open it in Excel the program insists in converting the column into numbers and showing the contents in scientific format. This requires the extra step of reformatting the column, which can be a real time-waster when one works with lots of files.

**How can I format a character vector of 20-digit numbers in R so that Excel doesn't display them in scientific notation?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of opening the csv file via `File->Open`, you can go to `Data->From Text` in Excel and on the last step specify the `Column data format` to be `Text`.

Not really sure though that you save any time by doing this, you can also consider using the `WriteXLS` (or some other direct to xls) package.

---

**edit**

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165042/stop-excel-from-automatically-converting-certain-text-values-to-dates) a much better way of forcing Excel to read as text:

```
write.csv(paste0('"=""', y, '"""'), 'y.csv', row.names = F, quote = F)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing me with a pre-Excel solution, but my actual problem involves a data frame, say `z <- data.frame(cbind(y, letter = c('a', 'b')))`. I want to tell `write.csv` that `z$y` is not numeric, but it can leave `z$letter` (and all the other variables in the real data frame) alone. How can I do that?

Comment: just apply the above `paste` to the columns you like, in this particular case: `z$y = paste0('"=""', z$y, '"""')`

Comment: Smart solution. Now I've got it the way I wanted. Thanks again!

Comment: write.csv(paste0("=\"", y, "\""), "y.csv", row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, select the column of numbers, and format them as text. (Format Cells -> Number tab -> Text in the list on the left)

Comment: Thank you for the input, but that's pretty much what I am doing now and would like to automate.