# Formatting issue of datetime while exporting to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel, datetime-format, export-to-csv

I am doing Export to Excel process in my asp.net application.

In that process, I am writting the DateTime value to excel using the below code:

```
string reqDate = item.requestedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
Response.Write(reqDate + "\t");
```

But the result in the excel file missing the **second**  part in the datetime like below:

```
4/3/2014 17:05
```

I want it look like **04/03/2014 05:05:19 PM**

How to do this?

Please help.

Comment: What is your `item.requestedDate` value exactly and what is your current culture?

Comment: its value is 04/03/2014 05:05:19 PM .I want to display as same

Comment: Hello sir, i also face same problem. if you get answer , please write here

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're exporting to CSV, not Excel.  Excel reads the CSV, recognizes a DateTime, and formats it using its default culture-specific format.

If you want to force it to be formatted as text, look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165042/stop-excel-from-automatically-converting-certain-text-values-to-dates).

Alternatively you could consider streaming a genuine Excel file, generated using a tool such as EPPlus or Aspose Cells, rather than CSV.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by how Excel parses DateTime's in CSV documents. More specifically, if the DateTime's `Day` property  is less than or equal to 12.

In your example (04/03/2014) `Day <= 12`, and Excel formats it in a way you don't want. However for DateTime's with `Day > 12` (e.g. 04/23/2014) Excel formats it as you'd expect.

A trick for getting DateTime's to display as you want in Excel is to wrap them in an Excel formula like this: `="04/03/2014 05:05:19 PM"`

```
if (item.requestedDate.Day <= 12)
    Response.Write("=\"" + item.requestedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + "\"");
```

Comment: In this example, is it not changing the data type to custom (string)? So sorting by date would fail. I encountered this with strings that begin with 0's and Excel assumed integer. Adding ' + value output it correctly but still sorts incorrectly.

Comment: @Anthony Yes the output is a string literal, which could lead to unexpected sorting. A workaround could be to use a "most to least significant" format such as "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! That tricking for getting DateTime's by Excel formula works!

And it works with milliseconds! Works without any cell formating!!!

My C# example for Excel export data:

```
x_sheet.Cells[your_row_id, your_column_id] = "=\"" + your_object.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff") + "\"";
```

Result at excel cell: ="08.19.2022 09:58:05.933"

[Excel printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXHX2.png)

I looked for that so long....

Thank You very much!

Comment: So basically "Thanks" is what your post is saying. Right?

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32810003)