# PHP Date Export To CSV Format

Tags: php, datetime, csv, export-to-csv, date-formatting

After export and when I open the CSV up, you'll notice column L formats only some of the dates properly. This happend on a couple other date columns as well. Is there anything I can do with PHP to ensure all dates are returned properly? Below id my function:

```
public function formatDateCI($date) {

    // If Birthdate Column
    if(strlen($date) == 10){
        $date = explode('-',$date);
        $m = $date[0];
        $d = $date[1];
        $Y = $date[2];
        $date = $Y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d;
    }

    $date = new DateTime($date);
    // Final Format 1983-24-12 00:00:00
    return date_format($date, 'Y-d-m H:i:s');
}
```

[image: Column L Date Format Issue]

Comment: How does the $date variable look like if it doesn't enter the If condition?

Comment: Were does `$date` come from is it a datetime column from a database?

Comment: Gabriel, if it doesn't enter the if condition it looks like 2014-08-07 21:04:19, Riggs, the brithdate column in the database is not a datetime. The other columns are datetime

Comment: But i still see the same issue on the other columns that are datetime

Comment: does that mean `birthdate` is a `date` column

Comment: birthdate says its a varchar(45)

Comment: You can force Excel to use text format with this fix : http://stackoverflow.com/a/165052/911718

Comment: See my answer and my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

Instead of:

```
$date = new DateTime($date);
```

>

Be sure to try an if else structure:

```
if(strlen($date) == 10){
        $date = explode('-',$date);
        $M= $date[0];
        $D = $date[1];
        $Y = $date[2];
       //this $date = $Y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d;
       //or this =>
       $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime($h, $m, $s, $M, $D, $Y));
    }else{
         $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
    }

    return $date;
```

Comment: This worked too, but some birthdates are returning as 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: @Hector You need to have a unified format for dates, try an if else structure like see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to do just this

```
public function formatDateCI($date) {
    return date('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00', strtotime($date));
}
```

In which case you probably dont even need to make it a method as it will fit nicely in the calling code.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

If you are using an American date format you will have to correct the format for `strtotime()` as it expects USA format dates to have a `/` seperator and not a `-` seperator. If it see a `-` seperator it expects a logical date format of some sort.

```
public function formatDateCI($date) {
    // correct USA date format for strtotime
    $date = str_replace('-','/',$date);
    return date('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00', strtotime($date));
}
```

Comment: Call to undefined function strtodate()

Comment: SORRY, my woops, corrected to `strtotime()` I guess I should not have had that pint with my dinner.

Comment: Thanks, this worked on all the columns that were datetime in the DB, but now many of the birthdate fields are returning as 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: What exactly is in the birthdate column, show some examples where is goes wrong?

Comment: If `birthdate` is an optional field i.e. can it be left blank by user? if so what is the default value set by your database for that column.

Comment: This was the DOB column example '12-24-1983', Got it working with the if statement above. The strtotime() did fix my other issues, thanks!