Convert DD/MM/YYYY to ISO 8601 format in Excel Sheet
I have a list of birthdays in the following format in Excel.
07/06/1987
04/04/1993
14/05/1973
13/07/1969
etc

I would like this to be converted to the format: 1987-06-07T11:31:01.805Z
How can I go about doing this in Excel?
Note: I understand the time is missing in my data set but we can assume the time is 9am or 10am or 12:00:01am

it is already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388761/how-to-convert-a-date-in-excel-to-iso-8601-format
