# How to convert numeric to string

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, excel, csv

Using VB.Net application

Creating a CSV file from SQL output in the application

When i open the csv into xls or xlsx file, i am getting a column as `1.02141E+15` instead of `123456789`

In SQL, When i add the below line in front of number

```
Select ''''  + 123456789  from table
```

Then I am getting output with single quote as `'123456789` in xls file instead of  `1.02141E+15`. I have tried with `'' + 123456789` and `' ' + 123456789` but result is same as  `1.02141E+15`

User don't want to format the excel sheet manually

What is the best input character pass to the query column to view the number properly in xls file
like 123456789 with out any single quote or character

Comment: Format the cell in Excel to use a number format rather than "General".

Comment: Client dont want to format the excel sheet manually

Comment: Then output it as a string, with double quotes around the value.  Note:  I think it will be imported into Excel as text rather than a number.

Comment: read : https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4

Comment: What does the CSV look like when you open it in notepad?

Comment: The reason that Excel is displaying your number that way is that the number can't fit into the column at Excel's default width of 8.43. Even if you could the text would be truncated by the next cell's boundary and you would still need to format the cell anyway. However, if that is acceptable, I would do as @GordonLinoff said and format it as a string [(try this, too)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023847/231316). Or, if your client can tolerate 3 clicks, click the upper left corner "select all cells" button and double-click any column's separator to automatically adjust widths.

Comment: Even if it is converted to string, it won't work. Only way to get around is to add a `'` before the number in excel. This way it doesn't bundle up into the exponential notation.

Comment: @Gopal - why do you `open the csv into xls or xlsx file`? why don't you define a new data connection and provide the SQL query? It will be well formatted that way.

Answer (score 0):

Or you must create programtatic the excell sheet in VB like that

**First (1) column will be a text, second (2) as General, third (3) as Number**

```
Sub formatColumns()
 Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
 Columns(2).NumberFormat = "General"
 Columns(3).NumberFormat = "0"
End Sub
```

you need like column (3).. 
and so on .. 
Happy codding ! :)