# How to escape forward slash in csv?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
status,-12/-34/567
```

This csv line, when opened in excel, gets converted to **status,0.000622471**

How to prevent this ?

Comment: Handled in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165042/stop-excel-from-automatically-converting-certain-text-values-to-dates).

Comment: That's not a backslash. It's a forward slash. If you want it to be treated as text, wrap it in quotes. so: `status,="-12/-34/567"`

Comment: thanks. ="-12/-34/567" worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

status,="-12/-34/567" mentioned by TZHX resolved the issue.
thanks.