# LinqToCSV format column as Text

Tags: c#, linqtocsv

I'm using LinqToCSV to output a List to CSV.  Snippet of sample code is as follows:

```
class Person
{
    [CsvColumn(Name = "Name", FieldIndex = 1)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [CsvColumn(Name = "Address 1", FieldIndex = 2)]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [CsvColumn(Name = "Telephone", FieldIndex = 3)]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}


private void OutputToCSV(string filenamePrefix, List<Person> people)
{
    CsvFileDescription outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
    {
        SeparatorChar = ','
        FirstLineHasColumnNames = true, 
        FileCultureName = "en-GB"
    };

    CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
    cc.Write(
        people,
        @"C:\temp\people.csv",
        outputFileDescription);            
}
```

The issue I have is with the telephone number.  If it is in the object as 0123456789012 then when I open the CSV in Excel it is seen as a number and the leading zero is removed.  I'd like to pre format the column in the CSV as text.

According to [Stop Excel from automatically converting certain text values to dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165042/stop-excel-from-automatically-converting-certain-text-values-to-dates) I can start the field with an equals and put the value in quotes, but is there an attribute I can set which will mean that LinqToCSV will do this for me?  I don't really want to use LinqToCSV, then open the file and edit it to get it how I want.

Comment: Instead of CSV, use EPPlus to create a *real* Excel file. CSV doesn't have any formatting information so there's no way to tell whether a field is text or a number

Comment: Panagiotis: This looks like a good alternative and a great way to create Excel files, but not CSV files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your intent to create a CSV or an Excel file? If the latter, then wouldn't it be much easier if you have instead used Epplus from Nuget? ie:

```
void Main()
{
  ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
  List<Person> people = new List<Person> {
    new Person { UserName="Cetin", Address1="A1", Telephone="012345"},
    new Person { UserName="Timbo", Address1="A2", Telephone="023456"},
    new Person { UserName="StackO", Address1="A3", Telephone="0 345 6789 01 23"},
  };


  var wsEnum = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MyPeople");

  //Load the collection starting from cell A1...
  wsEnum.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(people, true, TableStyles.Medium9);
  wsEnum.Cells[wsEnum.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
  //...and save
  var fi = new FileInfo(@"d:\temp\People.xlsx");
  if (fi.Exists)
  {
    fi.Delete();
  }
  pck.SaveAs(fi);
}

class Person
{
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public string Address1 { get; set; }
  public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The question is for CSV files, not Excel files. CSV files are often opened in Excel, but also used to import into other systems.

Comment: Read what I say at top. CSV means Comma Separated Value and is used in transferring data between different mediums and is not meant to be a particular for Excel - "are often opened in Excel" is an incorrect statement. It is often for only those who use Excel often.

Comment: I'll have a look at Epplus.  As far as I'm aware there's no requirement to import the file into anything else, I think it's just used in Excel so this will do the job.

Comment: Oh then certainly look into it. It is simple and it creates the xlsx file, even if Excel is not installed in user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using OutputFormat to force it ToString(). You may also be able to combine it with your other fix and use OutputFormat="=C" but I have not tried that.

```
[CsvColumn(Name = "Telephone", FieldIndex = 3, OutputFormat = "C")]
public string Telephone { get; set; }
```

Comment: It is not the output format that is the problem. All CSV entries are text, but Excel reads it as a number and amends it. the number has to be changed to have a leading '='.

Comment: No, that would convert it to a formula. Excel uses a single quote (') for fields that contain numeric data that should be treated as text

Comment: I'd already tried putting a single quote directly into the CSV.  Excel displays the quote!

Answer (score -1):

As you say, this is an Excel issue and you need to the data to have a leading = sign, so that 0123456789012 becomes ="0123456789012".

You can use the OutputFormat to change the format, but you would need to play around with the formatting:

```
[CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 2, OutputFormat = "dd MMM HH:mm:ss")]
```

Comment: It *isn't* an Excel issue actually, there's no way to tell that the field contains a string or number. CSV doesn't have any type information, so Excel tries to guess the field types while importing

Comment: All CSV files are just text. However, Excel will translate the value into a numeric, so adding the '=' sign tells Excel to treat it as a number.

Comment: No, it will convert it to a formula. Excel uses the single quote (') in these cases. Better to create a *real* Excel file though. It's just as easy and a lot safer

Comment: We don't know if an Excel file is needed, the question says CSV, which is being opened in Excel. We don't know if the file is to be used elsewhere as a CSV.

Comment: "Elsewhere" would likely be a database where it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Any field prefix makes the CSV inappropriate for use by any other application. You couldn't import such a file in a database for example, without first stripping the prefix. So a prefix pretty much requires Excel - or another application that treats prefixes in the same way

Comment: Ha ha..Good point!
Then this is only a problem if it is to be imported into Excel. If so, Cetin's answer would be the best solution.
I'm glad I am aware of EPPlus now.

Comment: Why the downvote? This isn't wrong if the import is for Excel.