# How to avoid automatically change data type in .CSV file

Tags: java, sql, excel

I have created an application in java language and I have used MySQL as a DBMS. I have a button in this application which export my data to .CSV file.

The problem is that when I open .CSV file, it automatically change the data. For example, `00001` will becomes `1`.

How can I avoid automatically change data type in excel?

Comment: `Import` (`Data` ► `Get External Data` ► `From Text`) instead of `Open`; and pre-format the column as text

Comment: Yeah, that Import Data -> From Text Menu is your friend. That has nothing to do with java or sql.

Comment: thank you, if we import data as text we can specify data type

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a little bit more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the `*.csv` directly in Excel, then all columns will be read as type `general` (means there is an automated guessing for the value type).

If you import the file as text into the current sheet you can specify the value delimiter and also the type of each column.

Answer (score 1):

May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165042/stop-excel-from-automatically-converting-certain-text-values-to-dates) is related. 
In that case the solution would be to save value as

```
"=""00001"""
```

This will be interpretered as text by excel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried prefixing it with a single quote?

Example: `'00001`

It's just a guess based on how that value would need to be typed into Excel for it to treat it as a string and not to convert the value into a numeric `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that might work: when creating the csv, what value are you writing? Are you writing 0001 (so, as number); or "0001"?

You see, when this column is seen as number ... then it might be reasonable that you get 1 for 00001.

So, tried saving that the values for that column as "00001"?