# Rails axlsx gem - Formula not escaping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, rubygems, axlsx

Is there a way to ignore executing a formula while rendering spreadsheet?

Currently, `sheet.add_row("=10+10")` will evaluate 20, even if I give `:formula => :false` or `:type=> :string`

The only hacky way is to provide a single quote, but it's not a pretty approach.

Comment: Can you give a complete minimal working example. I get an `Invalid Data "=10+10" for array_to_cells. must be Array. (ArgumentError)` with your code snipplet. I have to use `sheet.add_row(["=10+10"])`

Comment: It cannot be anything but a string type.  Else if fails.  And if it's string, with an '=' then it's considered a formula and executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the source code of the gem in question, the following code is there:

```
def is_formula?
   @type == :string && @value.to_s.start_with?('=')
end
```

It means that anything of type string with '=' will be treated like a formula.  And the only accepted types are date, string, integer, float etc.  Anything else in place of :type => :string and it does not accept it.

As an alternative, I had to open the class `cell_serializer.rb` in the gem and reimplement the method in a custom way to get rid of cell.is_formula? check.

```
def string_type_serialization(cell, str='')
      if cell.is_formula?
        formula_serialization cell, str
      elsif !cell.ssti.nil?
        value_serialization 's', cell.ssti.to_s, str
      else
        inline_string_serialization cell, str
      end
 end
```

Reimplemented method:

```
def string_type_serialization(cell, str='')
        if !cell.ssti.nil?
          value_serialization 's', cell.ssti.to_s, str
        else
          inline_string_serialization cell, str
        end
end
```

I realize it's a hacky way, but it affects system wide code.  If I need anything complex in future, I can always make changes to one central place.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer for this in [Stop Excel from automatically converting certain text values to dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165042/stop-excel-from-automatically-converting-certain-text-values-to-dates)

```
require 'axlsx'
Axlsx::Package.new do |p|
  p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => 'DATA') do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row(['="10+10"', 'Maybe this is the best solution'])
    sheet.add_row(["'10+10", 'Hack with single quote'])
  end    
  p.serialize('test.xlsx')
end
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: That was the hacky way I used, but then it does not look good.  I am checking for a better solution.

Comment: Can you try `sheet.add_row([" =10+10"])` (see the space before the =). I can't test it actual (no installed excel), but if I open it with Open Office it works.

Comment: That didn't help, at least with MS Office 2016.

Answer (score 1):

I found another approach.  In the approach mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40815038/259889) answer, although the formula is not executed when the spreadsheet opens, it is evaluated if the user clicks  on it and then blurs away.  This might not be the best solution.

Better solution is to wrap any excel functions in [TEXT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) function.  This ensures the formulae  is not executed.

e.g.

> = 9 + 9 can be substituted with =TEXT("9+9","#"), and it will be printed as it is, without evaluation.