# Excel showing empty cells when importing file created with csv module

Tags: python, excel, csv, cells

I have a .csv with rows that are something like:

```
"Review",Clean Review
"The hotel _was, re3ally good",the hotel was really good
```

but when I was open with excel 2013 the cells with the double quotes are showing empty on the sheet, and I can only see the text in the formula bar. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

excel sheet kinda looks like:

```
|          |Clean Review|
|          |the hotel wa|
```

I have opened the .csv in notepad and there doesn't seem to be hidden characters causing this behavior

I used Python's csv module to create the .csv

**it especially happens if you drag and expand the first column**

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided.  Can you upload a csv file that demonstrates the problem when opened in Excel?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld sure, what would be the best way to upload a file for you to download?

Comment: Use any of the various file-sharing sites.  I've seen people use OneDrive, DropBox, and others; and edit your question to include the link.  Make sure when YOU download the file from wherever you put it, that the problem is still reproduceable.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld if you're still interested I have uploaded the .csv, link in question

Comment: There is a carriage return character after the 'w'.  Increase the **height** of row 1 and you will see it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld ok thanks very much for your help, if you add that comment as an answer I can give you the accept points

Comment: I've done that.  But I suggest the issue is in how your Python script is creating the CSV (or possibly in the actual original source for the csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your CSV file.  There is a <kbd>CR</kbd> after the `w` in `Review`.  And `Review` is actually on the 2nd line of A1 (seen if you increase the **height** of row 1).

Here is an analysis of the characters at the beginning of your actual CSV with the character and the ASCII code.  Note the `10` after the `w`

```
"              34 
R              82 
e              101 
v              118 
i              105 
e              101 
w              119     
               10 
"              34
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
="Review",Clean Review
="The hotel _was, re3ally good",the hotel was really good
```

This forces the value to be text and not something else.
Haven't tried but theoretically should work.

Please check this and more solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165042/stop-excel-from-automatically-converting-certain-text-values-to-dates)