# csv module automatically writing unwanted carriage returns

Tags: python, excel, list, csv, row

When using pythons csv module to create a csv it is automatically putting carriage return characters at the end of strings if the string has a comma inside it e.g:

```
['this one will have a carriage return, at the end','this one wont']
```

in an excel sheet this will turn out like:

```
 |       |this on|
```

because of the extra carriage return, it will also surround the string with the comma inside in double quotes, as expected.

The code I am using is:

```
with open(oldfile, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

How do I create a csv using the same data format which won't have carriage returns if the strings have commas inside, I don't mind the strings being surrounded by double quotes though

Here's a link to the diagnosis of the problem with the output .csv:

[Excel showing empty cells when importing file created with csv module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575973/excel-showing-empty-cells-when-importing-csv)

It's the accepted answer.

I have changed my code to:

```
with open(oldfile, 'w', newline='', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

I am now getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'quoting' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in CSV module of python has the option: `csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`. When this option is added as an argument to the writer, it adds quotemarks when the delimeter is in the given string: `"your text, with comma", "other field"`. This will eliminate the need for carriage returns.
The code is:

```
with open(oldfile, 'w') as csvfile: writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) for row in data: writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: when I use the following code instead of my questions:    with open(oldfile, 'w', newline='', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) as csvfile: I get the error: NameError:  
     name 'csv' is not defined

Comment: You should import the standard CSV module: import csv

Comment: oh yea sorry my bad

Comment: The argument I talked about has to be added to the writer class: csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

Comment: I am getting the error: TypeError: 'quoting' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.52

Comment: Use: csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

Comment: yep sorry I think I'm putting it in the wrong place, thanks for your help