# hyphen symbol change to slash in csv in java

Tags: java, excel, csv

I'm generating csv file in java using following string

```
108176,2019-09-16,11-15-2019
```

when open this file in notepad++ it shows as this format

[image]

but when I open it in excel it shows different format ( **hyphen symbol change to slash** ).

[image]

what was the error and how can I get hyphen instead of slash?

Comment: This is most probably the way your sheet displays dates (also note the different ordering of the month and day) .

Comment: yes but I want to it display as general or text format

Comment: Not sure about a duplicate, but have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029740/force-excel-to-open-csv-without-formatting?rq=1

Comment: @Arnaud can I set date as general or Text format, I need to display date with hyphen