# Programmatically generated CSV file format issue for Excel and Numbers

Tags: ios, excel, csv

In my iOS project, I have programmatically generated csv file from my data. Most of time, it looks all good for `Microsoft Excel` and `Apple Numbers` to open with.

But when the cell data is something like `5 - 60`, it seems Excel would automatically convert it to date value like `May-60`, while Numbers open it correctly.

I have found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/165052/833885, so the solution makes Excel happy is using `"=""5 - 60"""`. But this will make Numbers shows `="5 - 60"`......

You can quickly generate empty csv file to test what I described above.

Is is possible to generate csv file that makes all world happy???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this `'5 - 60`. This will make excel read it as a string. Although I haven't tested this

Comment: @Zac It will show '5 - 60 instead of 5 - 60 on Excel

Comment: I'm presuming that's no good to you? could you not read that when you parse the file?

Comment: @Zac What I mean is in your method, there is additional ' as a prefix, I don't want it if it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new file in excel and import from the data ribbon tab - this gives options to specify the data types for 'columns' in the csv. A bit of a pain but will avoid the issue.

Comment: OK, this is working around! I will wait until whether there is better solution. Thanks!