# Why string element of a list converted to integer when saved in CSV file?

Tags: python, string, list, csv, integer

I have a list of lists below:

```
mylist = [['HBASE-5727', 2, '66772ce043', '1044d5e353'],
          ['HBASE-5286', 2, '180b41f518', '0132176084'],
          ['HBASE-532', 3, 'ef5bb6f316', 'fb2db8cdaa']
         ]
```

I need to save that list into CSV file. I wrote this code:

```
with open("numberofbugs.csv",'w') as csvfile:
     header = ['bug_id', 'number_of_bugs', 'first_commitID', 'last_commitID']
     writers = csv.writer(csvfile)
     writers.writerow(header)
     for item in mylist:
          writers.writerow(item)
```

However, the fourth element in the second sublist is written as integer `132176084`. Here's the CSV file resulted:

```
bug_id     | number_of_bugs | first_commitID | last_commitID |
--------------------------------------------------------------
HBASE-5727 |              2 | 66772ce043     | 1044d5e353    |
HBASE-5286 |              2 | 180b41f518     |     132176084 |
HBASE-532  |              3 | ef5bb6f316     | fb2db8cdaa    |
```

Why is it happen and how to keep the type of the element as it is written in the list (as `string`), so the value still `0132176084` instead of `132176084`?

Comment: Cannot confirm. How did you open the file - in Excel or in a text editor? In the former case, it was probably Excel that converted the strings to numbers. Judging by indentation, it was Excel indeed.

Comment: Will second @DyZ comment above. or u can try `str(item)` in `writers.writerow(str(item))`

Comment: yes, I open the file using excel. Is it possible to keep the type as a string in excel?

Comment: It is possible - but it's a different question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165042/stop-excel-from-automatically-converting-certain-text-values-to-dates

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you could pretend that your third and forth columns are formulas by enclosing them with `="....."` as follows:

```
import csv

mylist = [['HBASE-5727', 2, '66772ce043', '1044d5e353'],
          ['HBASE-5286', 2, '180b41f518', '0132176084'],
          ['HBASE-532', 3, 'ef5bb6f316', 'fb2db8cdaa']
         ]

with open("numberofbugs.csv", 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    header = ['bug_id', 'number_of_bugs', 'first_commitID', 'last_commitID']
    writers = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writers.writerow(header)

    for item in mylist:
        item[2:4] = ['="{}"'.format(c) for c in item[2:4]]
        writers.writerow(item)
```

The resulting `numberofbugs.csv` file would then look as follows when viewed in a text editor:

```
bug_id,number_of_bugs,first_commitID,last_commitID
HBASE-5727,2,"=""66772ce043""","=""1044d5e353"""
HBASE-5286,2,"=""180b41f518""","=""0132176084"""
HBASE-532,3,"=""ef5bb6f316""","=""fb2db8cdaa"""
```