# How do I control the format of columns when I use the write.csv function?

Tags: r, excel

I've created a dataframe in R and one of my columns convert a date such as `01/08/2018` (dd/mm/yyyy) into text form `Aug-18` (mmm-yy). However, when I write this to csv using the write.csv function, Excel automatically converts this to date.

Is there a way I can specify the column type to be "Text" so that Excel doesn't change it to date format?

Comment: why don't you write into `xlsx` right away? google: `r openxlsx`

Comment: @Jaap I was about to write the same. Excel estimates the "right" types from CSV. Use `openxlsx` to have control over stuff!

Comment: Excel's formatting as a date, text, etc. is up to Excel, not R. There's no formatting or data types in a CSV file--it's just text

Comment: @AndreElrico I mostly combine `writeData` and `addStyle` from `openxlsx`, which gives you quite some control over how stuff is displayed in Excel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165042/stop-excel-from-automatically-converting-certain-text-values-to-dates/6023847

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple trick that IMHO gets far too little attention is to pad your date colums with whitespace, e.g. `df$mydate <- paste(' ', df$mydate, sep='')`. This stops Excel from translating the text as dates.

I have started routinely doing that for all kinds of risky columns when doing R<->Excel transformations.

Taken from here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8