# Concatenate numbers into strings R programming

Tags: r, string, concatenation

I have two columns which contain numeric values. I would like to create a third by concatenating them as a string. I do that using the paste function. but on exporting the data to CSV. The third column gets converted into date
Desired output (Column C):

```
A      B     C
2      3     2-3
4      5     4-5
```

A & B is contained in a dataset called concat
code written till now as under

```
concat$C <- paste(concat$A,concat$B, sep="-", collapse = NULL)
```

This shows the desired output on screen but on writing to CSV, values in C column changes to date format.

Comment: Are you opening the csv file with Excel?

Comment: csv is just a text-based file. Perhaps the problem is in whatever application you are using to open that file.

Comment: @Aurele - yes. Is there a way to force it to recognise it as a string ?

Comment: In Excel you can change the format of a given column from the default "General" to "Text"

Comment: Maybe `paste("'", concat$A, concat$B, sep="-")`

Comment: @John Coleman. Yes. but regional settings affects the data. My class mate has asia settings and it shows DD-MM and I see MM-DD format. so we both get different outputs when we convert date to general in excel

Comment: This question seems relevant: [csv - Stop Excel from automatically converting certain text values to dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/165042/4996248)

Comment: @JohnColeman thank you john. i will check and get back

Comment: @Aurèle. It works.. but adds a seperator in the beginning so the output looks like '-3-4, '-5-3... is there a way to convert the output into string in R ?

Comment: Sorry, then I meant `paste0("'", concat$A, "-", concat$B)`

Comment: yes this works gives this output       "' 3 - 4" "' 4 - 5" "' 5 - 6" "' 2 - 7" "' 3 - 8"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out this a result of the way Excel (or other applications) interpret column formats. Similar problems happen if you want to export numeric columns with leading 0s, open US-format csv in countries like Germany, etc.

The easiest solution to all these problems is **to not open .csv in Excel directly**.

Instead open a new, empty Excel and use the **Import Assistant** in the **data tab**. This will allow you to import csv or any other separated-text-format and control the column formats before importing!

Be aware that simply opening .csv,.tsv, etc. in Exel and then saving in the original file format will overwrite all data to the Excel assumed data format! So always use the import assistant.

Comment: Thanks.. This is a really cool tip.. Never knew that it would change the original file format..